# How to get unique values from list in specific order?

Tags: python, list

I have a list with repeated values like below:

```
L1 = ['r-A','r-G','S1','r-A','S2','r-O','r-G','S2','S1','r-A']
```

And like to remove repeated elements containing 'r-' leaving the first value only in the corresponding position.

This is:

```
For 'r-A' select L1[0] and in output would be L2[0]
For 'r-G' select L1[1] and in output would be L2[1]
For 'r-O' select L1[5] and in output would be L2[4]
```

So the output list would be:

```
L2 = ['r-A','r-G','S1','S2','r-O','S2','S1']
```

Using `set()` I get the unique values but it shows them in different order and removes values that don´t contain `r-`

```
>>> list(set(L1))
['S2', 'S1', 'r-A', 'r-G', 'r-O']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
L1 = ['r-A','r-G','S1','r-A','S2','r-O','r-G','S2','S1','r-A']
L2 = []
for item in L1:
    if 'r-' in item and item  in L2:
         continue
    else:
        L2.append(item)
print(L2)
```

Output:

```
['r-A', 'r-G', 'S1', 'S2', 'r-O', 'S2', 'S1']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final = []
[final.append(x) for x in L1 if not x in final or not "r-" in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple for loop, first check string startwith `r-` then check if it is already in output list else add it

```
L1 = ['r-A','r-G','S1','r-A','S2','r-O','r-G','S2','S1','r-A']
result = list()

for i in L1:
    if i.startswith('r-'):
        if i not in result:
            result.append(i)
    else:
      result.append(i)

print(result) # ['r-A', 'r-G', 'S1', 'S2', 'r-O', 'S2', 'S1']
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've tried your code, but I'm getting different order `['r-A', 'r-G', 'r-O', 'S1', 'S2', 'S2', 'S1']
`
`

Comment: No i get this as output `['r-A', 'r-G', 'S1', 'S2', 'r-O', 'S2', 'S1']` @GerCas

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well:

```
 L1 = ['r-A','r-G','S1','r-A','S2','r-O','r-G','S2','S1','r-A']

 newL1 = []
 for element in L1:
    if element == "S1":
      newL1.append(element)
    elif element == "S2":
      newL1.append(element)
    else:
      if element not in newL1:
        newL1.append(element)
 print(newL1)
```

Output:

```
>>>['r-A', 'r-G', 'S1', 'S2', 'r-O', 'S2', 'S1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Short one with O(n) time.

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(L1, 1)
>>> [x for x in L1 if x[:2] != 'r-' or d.pop(x, 0)]
['r-A', 'r-G', 'S1', 'S2', 'r-O', 'S2', 'S1']
```

I'm keeping track of the `r-`-elements I can still use instead of the ones I have already used. It's a little easier because `dict.pop` can be used in an expression and both removes and returns a value.